# Is it possible to centralize to import of Angular modules?

Tags: angular

I wonder if it possible to centralize the import of Angular modules?
For instance, I'm using the `NgbModule` from `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`.  Do I have to import the module into each module that will use the `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` features?

I thought that I can centralize those kind of import in the SharedModule and then after importing the SharedModule all dependencies will available.

I think that I have overestimated the role of the ShareModule.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: We take a "module-per-component" approach in most cases to prevent bloat. If something is truly shared across every module, we'll have a `shared.module.ts`, but that module is typically extremely light.

Answer (score 2):

You can but it's not advised.

There is something called tree-shaking and module bundling in Angular apps. Those features are used to reduce your final bundle size.

If you create a SharedModule that you import everywhere, you loose the perks of those features and your final bundle will have duplicated code all over the place, as well as dead code.

Comment: Related read: [What is Tree Shaking and Why Would I Need It?](/questions/45884414/what-is-tree-shaking-and-why-would-i-need-it)